# Record Sounds from AudioContext (Web Audio API)

Tags: audio-recording, html5-audio, web-audio-api, webkitaudiocontext

Is there a way to record the audio data that's being sent to `webkitAudioContext.destination`?

The data that the nodes are sending there is being played by the browser, so there should be some way to store that data into a (.wav) file.

Comment: you might want to take a look at:
https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs :)

Comment: Hello @jellyksong, have you solved the issue of webaudio api recording

Comment: @Jatt.net Yes, I just used the Recorderjs library listed as the accepted answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Audio recording with HTML5 Web Audio Api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13003852/audio-recording-with-html5-web-audio-api)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, there's not a native way to do that, but as Max said in the comment above, Recorderjs does essentially this (it doesn't chain onto the destination, but is a ScriptProcessorNode you can connect other nodes to, and have its input recorded.  I built on Recorderjs to do a simple audio file recorder - https://github.com/cwilso/AudioRecorder.

Comment: Still, recorder.js must work somehow - so there must be a way to do that. Fact that you don't want to bother explaining is not an excuse.

Comment: Your demo is pretty awesome! Thanks for sharing that!

Answer (score 3):

Sine to opus file: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamDestination

> In the following simple example, we create a
>   MediaStreamAudioDestinationNode, an OscillatorNode and a MediaRecorder
>   (the example will therefore only work in Firefox at this time.) The
>   MediaRecorder is set up to record information from the
>   MediaStreamDestinationNode.

Chrome supports it, too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder